# Trying to sort tags by count manytomany field Django

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

thank you for the time you spend reading my post so I'll get to the point.

I tried to arrange my most *common tags* in the order of the most used tags to the most unused first 5 values but I dont know how.
This is what I've tried :

**models.py**:

```py
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag


class BlogPost(models.Model): # blogpost_set -> queryset
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, null = True)
```

**context_processor.py**:

```py
def blog_cat_tags(request):
    # Top Tags
    most_common = BlogPost.objects.values('tags').annotate(truck_count=Count('tags')).order_by('-truck_count')
    most_common_n = Tag.objects.values('tag').annotate(truck_count=Count('tag')).order_by('-truck_count')
    common_tags = []
    for tag in most_common:
        common_tags.append(tag)
    common_tags = common_tags[:5]
```

This is the resault:

[image]

Tags are aranged in order but i cant get the name and if I change from *most_common* variable to *most_common_n* in **for** I get this.

[image]

But this is not the right order. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get name through `values`

```
def blog_cat_tags(request):

    most_common = BlogPost.objects.values('tags__tag').annotate(truck_count=Count(
         'tags')).order_by('-truck_count').values('tags__tag', 'truck_count')
    # Here you will get out put as
    # {'tags__tag':'Tag 1','truck_count':1} you can use it directly

    common_tags = []
    for tag in most_common:
        common_tags.append(tag['tags__tag'])
    common_tags = common_tags[:5]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me cause I seached for this answer for hours. Can you tell me some sources from where you learned how to work with annotate, order_by in case you have some links. Thank you agian

Comment: You're Welcome! You can look at this and practice by yourself https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/

Comment: That's perfect, I can improve myself once agian. I wish you the best

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late response.
You can achieve this with just a query like:

```
most_common = BlogPost.objects.values('tags__tag').annotate(truck_count=Count('tags')).order_by('-truck_count')[:5]
```

Result (most_common) would be:

```
[
    {'tags__tag': 'tag1', 'truck_count': 5}, 
    {'tags__tag': 'tag2', 'truck_count': 4},
    {'tags__tag': 'tag3', 'truck_count': 3}, 
    {'tags__tag': 'tag4', 'truck_count': 2},
    {'tags__tag': 'tag5', 'truck_count': 1}, 
]
```

Comment: Thank you, this one worked aswell. Unfortunately i cant give 2 right answers. :(